# Xcode debugger hangs entire system

Tags: xcode

I am trying to resolve a Bonjour network service, and there is a bug in my netServiceDidResolveAddress: handler, a null reference exception. When I run the app, it hits the bug, and Xcode drops into the debugger, showing the offending line and "Thread 1: Program received signal: EXC_BAD_ACCESS". All fine.

But when it does this, my entire system hangs. Not just Xcode, but the entire OS X UI is frozen. The mouse moves, and music and other background tasks seem to continue, but the UI is completely unresponsive. The only way out is a hard reboot of the entire system. Yikes.

I do a fair amount of low-level programming and this is happening more often than I'd like. I've seen the other questions here about Xcode itself freezing on breakpoints and exceptions but nothing about a full system hang.

Has anyone else encountered this? Any suggestions on recovering (or avoiding the issue entirely)?